# "Benefit" is to "pro" as what is to "con"?

Tags: analogy

What word would best suit this analogy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[*Drawback*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drawback)** is the first word that comes to mind. Other possibilities [listed by Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/benefit) are *disadvantage*, *hindrance*, *encumbrance*, *nuisance*, *obstacle*, or *detriment*. (Listed more-or-less in decreasing order of relevance, at least in my opinion.)

Comment: Consider "liability" as well

Comment: @Jason L. If Martha's answer clicks with you, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark for her, or at least giving her an up vote.

Comment: @Robusto Oh, sorry!

Answer (score 10):

**[Detriment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detriment)?**

I'm not sure exactly how *benefit* should relate to *pro*, but as *pro* and *con* are opposites, I would consider *detriment* to be appropriate.

Merriam-Webster also lists: *disadvantage, drawback, encumbrance, hindrance, impediment, minus* as antonyms for *benefit*.

Comment: I agree that "benefit" is not the best fit for "pro", but as the question was asked, this is the most accurate answer.